# Как работает валидация на JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Немного не понимаю как работают проверки на клиенте и сервере. Объясните, пожалуйста, на примере регистрации пользователей: Например, есть форма регистрации на php, далее делаю проверку на стороне клиента (по заданным правила ввода) и на стороне сервера (зарегистрирован ли человек с таким ником или email), проверка должна проходить без обновления страницы.

Как это всё нужно оформлять и как это работает?

Как я понял, проверка на стороне клиента сначала производится чистым JavaScript-ом, затем AJAX-ом на стороне сервера, и после проверки уже, к примеру, становится активна кнопка `"готово"` для отправки на сервер в БД с помощью PHP. Так? Или я неправильно понял всё?

P.S. Повторюсь, что не код нужен а именно понять в теории что и как работает.

Comment: Ну, например, так. Только после нажатия «Готово» сервер должен проверить всё ещё раз

Comment: почему и зачем? просто я правда не понимаю как это все работает

Comment: Потому что между первой проверкой на сервере и нажатием «Готово» пользователю ничего не мешает подделать данные так, чтобы пропустить проверку. Ну или просто за этот промежуток времени может успеть зарегистрироваться кто-то другой и ник окажется занят :)

Comment: Вообще, данным, пришедшим с клиента, доверять нельзя нигде и никогда. Любой пользователь может отключить все проверки на стороне клиента, отключить любой ajax, принудительно сделать активной кнопку «Готово» и отправить поддельные данные.

Comment: о как :О спасибо, не знал нюанса этого :)
"Только после нажатия «Готово» сервер должен проверить всё ещё раз" - как тогда эту проверку сделать, тем же php? Т.е. жмакаю "готово", еще раз проверяем данные на сервере только уже php, и если все хорошо то он там же и добавляет нового пользователя в БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Данные из формы отправляются на сервер для проверки посредством AJAX
2. Сервер проверяет входные данные и отдает ответ клиенту
3. Если все ок, клиент последний раз отправляет данные серверу (вдруг кто-то успел зарегистрироваться под теми же данными, пока пользователь втыкал в монитор).
4. Если все и тут ок, сервер регистрирует пользователя (обычно процесс регистрации короткий, поэтому все происходит без 3 пункта).

Гонять данные туда-сюда необходимо как раз таки для проверки.